Making testament or augmenting money resources to or with a defunct person to augment money sharing span
I wanted to ask whether it is legally possible for a person to leave testament or augment sharing of economic (and, other), resources, to (or with) a defunct person (for example, an ascendant who is dead) (or, could even, be, one or more, defunct (people, who, are dead)) in order to augment the number of people benefiting from the inheritance (in, a fair, allotment of resources), in, the family tree?
Thanks.
